# New warning after updating to Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, parsing

I'm trying to update an old App I last updated back on iOS 6 (I've been off the grid for a while). I had the following method:

```
-(NSString*)massResult: tipusCalcul:(NSNumber*)calcul massConcetracio:(NSString*)massaConcentracio volum:(NSString*)volum decimals:(NSString*)decimals;
```

It was no problem back then. But today I loaded the project with the lastest Xcode and the following warning appears:

```
'tipusCalcul' used as the name of the previous parameter rather than as part of the selector
```

I searched for the warning and I found that by just changing the method for:

```
-(NSString*)massResult: (NSNumber*)calcul massConcetracio:(NSString*)massaConcentracio volum:(NSString*)volum decimals:(NSString*)decimals;
```

the warning disappears.

The question is that I don't really understand the warning and why it does appear only with the new Xcode. If somebody could explain a bit, it would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You know in the first version you had no parameter defined for `massResult:`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the method signature:

```
-(NSString*)massResult: tipusCalcul:(NSNumber*)calcul massConcetracio:(NSString*)massaConcentracio volum:(NSString*)volum decimals:(NSString*)decimals;
```

You didn't specified the argument for `massResult:`. That's why the warning occurs.

You wrote it as:

```
massResult: tipusCalcul:(NSNumber*)calcul
```

So what happens is `XCode` will take this as:

```
massResult:(id)tipusCalcul :(NSNumber*)calcul
```

**tipusCalcul** will be taken as the parameter name of **massResult** instead of taking it as part of method name.

Comment: I've been programing with the Arduino platform for quite a while. While it's very similar, I think it has confused me big deal when returning to iOS. The intention of the method was to be named 'massResult', to return a String and to accept all these NSNumber and NSStrings as parameters. The method accepts all the parameters, calculates something and gives back a NSString.

Comment: @Marcal: So, now is there any issue with the method ?

Comment: It works fine. I guess I will have to re-learn some basics. Thanks.